# Auth0 passwordless Lock in ionic 2+ app

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3, auth0

Has anybody integrated the [auth0-lock-passwordless](https://www.npmjs.com/package/auth0-lock-passwordless) into an ionic 2+ hybrid app?

I don’t know how to handle the callback url

I have this code as a Angular service, called auth.service.ts:

```
import {Storage} from '@ionic/storage';
import {AuthHttp, JwtHelper, tokenNotExpired} from 'angular2-jwt';
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import Auth0LockPasswordless from 'auth0-lock-passwordless'

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
  private clientID = "XXXXXXXXXXX";
  private domain = "myapp.eu.auth0.com";
  jwtHelper: JwtHelper = new JwtHelper();
  lock: any;
  local: Storage = new Storage()
  user: Object;

  constructor(private authHttp: AuthHttp) {
    // If there is a profile saved in local storage
    this.lock = new Auth0LockPasswordless (this.clientID, this.domain)

    this.local.ready().then(() => {
        this.local.get('profile').then(profile => {
            this.user = JSON.parse(profile);
        })
    }).catch(error => {
      console.log(error);
    });
  }

  public authenticated() {
    // Check if there's an unexpired JWT
    return tokenNotExpired();
  }

  public login() {
    // Show the Auth0 Lock widget
    this.lock.emailcode({
      responseType: 'code',
      authParams: {
        scope: 'openid email',
        device: 'Mobile device'
      }
    }, (err, profile, token, accessToken, state, refreshToken) => {
      // CALLBACK CODE
      if (err) {
      // IF THERE'S AN ERROR, THIS CODE IS EXECUTED
        alert(JSON.stringify(err))
      } else {
       // IF EVERYTHING GOES FINE, THIS CODE IS NEVER CALLED, IT IS SENT TO A CALLBACK URL
      this.local.ready().then(() => {
        alert("profile: " + JSON.stringify(profile))
        alert("id_token: " + JSON.stringify(token))
        alert("refresh_token: " + JSON.stringify(refreshToken))
        alert("state: " + JSON.stringify(state))
        alert("err: " + JSON.stringify(err))
        this.local.set('profile', JSON.stringify(profile));
        this.local.set('id_token', token);
        this.local.set('refresh_token', refreshToken);
        this.user = profile;
        })
      }
    });    
  }

  public logout() {
    this.local.ready().then(() => {
        this.local.remove('profile');
        this.local.remove('id_token');
        this.local.remove('refresh_token');
        this.user = null;
    })
  }
}
```

I have tried to set the Auth0 application as a native and Single Web Page, with no success.

Here are some websites from where I got my inspiration from:

- https://auth0.com/docs/libraries/lock/v10
- https://blog.ionic.io/ionic-2-and-auth0/

To handle the callback I was thinking I could use ionic [Deeplinks](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/deeplinks/), but before going that way I wanted to be confirm that this is the correct way.

A side question is: what is the difference between Deeplinks and Cordova custom URL plugin?

Comment: show teh code plis

Comment: Added code and details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is to use their hosted auth pages, the auth0-lock-passwordless is deprecated and you will run into a few issues.

The email path returns you to a new callback page with in a typical web scenario, So you need a live authentication callback page that checks if it is returning with the tokens, then validates that. Since this is a hybrid app there maybe a work around. Auth0 support is ok but I think that they have't considered hybrid apps like this.

You may need to setup different sub accounts if you plan to use more than one login method. The hosted pages require specific js to be added inside their console, I don't have access to that code anymore.

In short the auth0-lock-passwordless path won't work.